# how to add a fragment to the navigation drawer menu item fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a store item fragment in the navigation drawer item menu in this fragment I will like to known how  to add another fragment to it if the user click on the  Imageview icon then still maintain my navigation drawer  below is my try

```
package com.example.entertainmentlab.ui.store;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.entertainmentlab.R;
import com.example.entertainmentlab.ui.setting.SettingViewModel;

public class StoreFragment extends Fragment {

    private StoreViewModel StoreViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StoreViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(StoreViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store, container, false);
       final ImageView MusicButton = root.findViewById(R.id.music_btn);





     //I want to move to the next Fragment if the user click the music icon

        MusicButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               try {

                   Fragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
                   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_store, fragment);
                   fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                   fragmentTransaction.commit();
               }catch (Exception e ){
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "erro  "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
       });
//        StoreViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
//            @Override
//            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
//                textView.setText(s);
//            }
//        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

[image]

if the user click the image icon I want to send he/she to the music fragment and then still maintaining the drawer and allow him to return back to the previous fragment

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to you use a `AlertDialog` for do this work but you can make full screen `AlertDialog`...

Comment: No I don't think that is the best solution to the problem